# Test strings from `ls /dev` and echo only block files

Tags: file, testing, echo, block

Can someone please explain how can I compare the results of

```
for i in `ls /dev`

do 
   echo $i
```

I only want to print the block special files from **/dev** but I don't know how to compare the strings in the list of file names

done

Comment: Can you please re-format your question so that code looks like code? Use the code button or indent all code with four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)?

```
$ find /dev -type b
/dev/loop7
/dev/loop6
/dev/loop5
...(snip)...
```

This tells find to start in `/dev` and only show files of type `b` which here, means "block" devices.  The default action of find is to simply print the file name.

If you still want to use this in a loop, you can do:

```
for dev in $(find /dev -type b); do
    echo "Device: $dev"
done
```